# How to asynchronously submit a form when clicking a control, Ajax-style?

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

In a Rails3 app, I have a boolean attribute `root` represented by a radio control (*not checkbox*) and I want to be able to automatically save the new value of `root` - Ajax-style.

```
<%= form_tag(set_root_project_page_path(@project, page), :remote => true, :method => :put ) do -%>
  <%= radio_button_tag('root', page.id, page.root?, :onclick => "this.form.submit();") %>
  <%= submit_tag 'set root', :disable_with => 'wait...' %>
<% end -%>
```

I currently have 2 submit options:

1. the `submit_tag` works as expected: the action is called through an XHR, and my `set_root.js.erb` template updates the page accordingly, *but* I don't want to have to click a separate button for that, so then I tried:
2. adding `:onclick => "this.form.submit();"` to my radio control. This submits the form, but in a classical, non-ajax way, so I get an error for missing the *html* template.

What should I do to have my form submitted asynchronously when clicking the radio control, (*maybe an UJS approach*)?

*Note: I'm using jQuery in my project.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `:onclick => "$(this.form).trigger('submit.rails')`

Answer (score -1):

Use form serialization: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/